# append binary values of integers read from an array

Tags: java, arrays, binary, byte, radix

I have an array of integers.I read each value using a for loop. Now i want to append the binary of each value and get the decimal of the appended binary.

eg.

array=>  01 05
binary=> 00000001  00000101
appended binary=> 0000000100000101 which gives the decimal 261.

How do i do this?

please help.

Comment: That's kind of an inefficient way to compute base-256 values. Is this homework?

Comment: no this is not homework.... i have some array in which the 1st two bytes give the size of the remaining values that are useful.

Comment: The size of the remaining values? Then you don't want to be messing with merging binary strings together. This sounds like framing.

Comment: I assume it has to be: "I have an array of **bytes**."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is not homework, there is no need to perform the inefficient intermediary step of "converting to binary" (integers in computers are *already* stored in binary format!)

```
public class Testy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 5 };
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int val = arr[i];
            sum = (sum << 8) + val;
        }
        System.out.println("final: " + sum);
    }
}
```

And if you are going to have more than 3 integers to include, you should make `sum` a `long` instead of an `int`, otherwise you may get overflow.

By the way, how is your for loop getting the values? If it is reading individual bytes and converting them to ints, it might make more sense to read whole shorts or ints in one go, although watch out for endianness.

Comment: Yow, that's more efficient :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Testy {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 1, 5 };
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            int val = arr[i];
            String s = String.format("%08s", Integer.toBinaryString(val));
            sw.append(s);
        }
        System.out.println("final: " + Integer.parseInt(sw.toString(), 2));
    }
}
```

Result: 261. Hope that helps :)

Comment: The other answer works better and is more efficient, you'd be better off using that :)

Comment: I'm going to learn you something :D. Try this: change the format to **`"%08s"`** and remove the replace part.